# How do I check the size of a HashMap for a conditional statement

Tags: java, hashmap, size, conditional-statements

Sorry I'm really new to programming. I'm messing around and making a simple text based game and I am stuck at trying to check the size of this HashMap in my conditional statement.

Here is the method:

```
/**
* Lists all the items in a room.
*/
public String getItemList()
{
    String NoItemList = "There are no items in this room.";
    String ItemList = "Items:"; Set<String> keys = items.keySet(); 

    for(String item : keys) 
    {
        ItemList += " " + item; 
    }

    if (items.size < 1)
    {
        return NoItemList;
    }

    if (items.size > 1)
    {
        return ItemList;
    }
}
```

How can I get it to work so that if there are items in the HashMap it will return ItemList, and if there are none to return NoItemList?

Thanks

Comment: `size` is not a field, it's a *method*, use `size()`

Answer (score 2):

On `HashMap` or `Collection` (which `HashMap` implements) [size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size%28%29) is a method use:

```
items.size()
```

The conditional could be rewrote to:

```
if (items.size() < 1)
{
    return NoItemList;
}else{
    return ItemList;
}
```

Or if your comfortable with ternary expressions:

```
return (items.isEmpty()) ? NoItemList:ItemList;
```

**Notice** this form of the method uses the [isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty%28%29) method which is a shortcut for checking if the list does not contain any items.

Comment: That's what I have it as at the moment but it doesn't compile - I get the error: size is not public in java.util.HashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: @MrAsstastic Notice that invoke the method using `()` where the provided code does not.

Comment: BTW, is `items` declared elsewhere in the code?  I do not see a declaration for it?

Comment: Yeah it is declared in the beginning of the class, I got it to work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code:

```
    if (items.size() == 0)
{
    return NoItemList;
}

if (items.size() > 0)
{
    return ItemList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size()` method to check the size of hashMap as below :

```
ItemList.size()  --> Return the size of map
```